# when using pyautogui hotkeys dont seem to work

Tags: python, pyautogui

when using hotkeys with pyautogui they dont work in any way. i have used to diffrent methods to get it to work.
is there any other methods i should try or a fix for the methods im using?

```
pyautogui.keyDown(ctrl)
pyautogui.keyDown(t)
pyautogui.keyUp(ctrl)
pyautogui.keyUp(t)
```

NameError: name 'ctrl' is not defined
is the error i get here.

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl , t')
```

just doesnt work in anyway

can anyone help
im trying to automate opening tabs and other things but i cant get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

`pyautogui.hotkey()` can be unreliable, and there is a much better way to automate opening and closing tabs. Instead, you can use `webbrowser` like this:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open("https://example.com") #opens tab in default browser

webbrowser.open("https://example.com", new=1) #opens a tab in a second browser (if possible)
```

Unfortunately, `webbrowser` cannot close tabs. If you need to close tabs, and `pyautogui.hotkey()` doesn't work, you can try using `keyboard`:

```
import keyboard

keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+w') #closes the tab
```

Answer (score 0):

https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#keyboard-keys

From the docs:

> The following are the valid strings to pass to the press(), keyDown(), keyUp(), and hotkey() functions:

Note the values in the array that follows are strings.

So `pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')` is fine, but `pyautogui.keyDown(ctrl)` would throw an error, unless you had previously declared a variable named `ctrl`.